# Calling React.unmountComponentAtNode but return false whatever I tried

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am confused with the use of unmountComponentAtNode, as @chenglou said, I should pass the container of the component but not the targetDOM of it.But if I have a parent component that displays:

```
var Fruit = React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        return (
            <div id="fruit">
                <Apple></Apple>
                <Grapes></Grapes>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
var Apple = React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        return (
            <div>I am an apple ~</div>
        );
    }
});
var Grapes = React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        return (
                <div>I am grapes ~</div>
        );
    }
});
React.render(<Fruit />,document.getElementById('app'));
```

and I want to remove the Apple component but retain the Grapes. I tried to use the unmoutComponentAtNode like this:
React.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById('fruit')) 
but it still return false.Is document.getElementById('fruit') not a container of Apple ?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? How about conditionally rendering the component instead?

Comment: I'm puzzled by why ReactDOM isn't used at all when rendering or unmounting component. Also, you can only unmount components from parents that weren't rendered by React.

Comment: @azinum It is hard to say.There is a navigation bar and a table in my page. The navigation bar is not necessary in every page but exists with the table.So I mix them together. Now I want to change the table component to another one but remains the navigation bar. The only solution I can think of is to unmount the table component. But the wrapper contains the navigation bar either.

Comment: @EzraChang Thanks, Now I know that I must unmount components from plain HTMLDOMElement that weren't rendered by React. And I am interested in the problem that the ReactDOM isn't used. Can you have a more detail description?

Comment: ReactDOM typically takes care of all of the operations involving mounting (rendering) and unmounting of components. You can read about it here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdom

This is the method pertinent to your situation: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdom.unmountcomponentatnode